Modify Zeppelin Notebooks though VS Code
I recently joined a company that has all the data ingestion made using Zeppelin Notebooks that we access through SSH tunnels.
Is it possible to maintain and version this code using VS Code?
How can I setup this?
The notebooks run with kubernetes pods, if it helps somehow.
My idea is to migrate to something more easier and clean to access and maintain but for now I'm stuck with this solution...
Several searches produced close to nothing that seem to work.
What I want to achieve is something like opening a tunnel, connecting to our repo , modify and version using VS code without the need to open a web browser.

You might try the unofficial Zeppelin Notebook extension with Remote-SSH.
FYI, The local notebook file will sync its metadata with the server when changes happen in cells. To make git version control easier, when you compare a notebook in history, you may disable metadata change view via "..." botton at the top right corner.
